# Has Azure the support for native Kubernetes?

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I have one simple question - has Azure the support for native Kubernetes? I mean, is it possible to make a Kubernetes installation on my own, without using Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, you just need to create a Linux virtual machine in Azure and manually install Kubernetes on top of it.
Exact steps and actions would be different, depending on Linux distribution you choose.
You can find more details about it, for example [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/)

Comment: Have to add that that will make it more expensive as the aks master nodes are free.